# Add .mpp file to list <>

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am working with .mpp files ... the first thing I do is read the file with an .mpp extension and that is going well for me, now what I am trying to do is add that file to a list but I can't get it.

I am something new in this

```
private void Btn_Actualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog theDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (theDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string fileName = theDialog.FileName.ToString();
            Load(fileName);
        }
    }

    public new string Load(string fileName)
    {
        MSProject.ApplicationClass app = null;
        string retVal = "";
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

        try
        {
            // execute the Microsoft Project Application
            app = new MSProject.ApplicationClass();

            // Do not display Microsoft Project
            app.Visible = false;

            // open the project file.
            if (app.FileOpen(fileName, true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, MSProject.PjPoolOpen.pjPoolReadOnly, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing))
            {
                // go through all the open projects--there should only be one
                foreach (MSProject.Project proj in app.Projects)
                {
                    // go through all the tasks in the project
                    foreach (MSProject.Task task in proj.Tasks)
                    {
                        // add Microsoft Project Task to arraylist                          
                        //tasks.Add(new Task(task));
                        //tasks.Add(task);
                        List<Task> tasks1 = new List<Task>();

                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                retVal = "The MS Project file " + fileName + " could not be opened.";
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            retVal = "Could not process the MS Project file " + fileName + "." + System.Environment.NewLine + ex.Message + System.Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace;
        }

        // close the application if is was opened.
        if (app != null)
        {
            app.Quit(MSProject.PjSaveType.pjDoNotSave);
        }
        return retVal;
    }
```

Where I want to add the result of reading the file is in this part of my code

```
foreach (MSProject.Task task in proj.Tasks)
                    {
                        // add Microsoft Project Task to arraylist                          
                        //tasks.Add(new Task(task));
                        //tasks.Add(task);
                        List<Task> tasks1 = new List<Task>();

                    }
```

Searching the web already tried several things but so far it has not worked for me and the list is always 0

Comment: Why did you comment out `tasks.Add(task);`? That should be how you add it to your list. You might have to change your list declaration to `List<MSProject.Task>` though, depending on the namespaces you're using. My guess is that is why its qualified in your loop, in which case your `List<Task>` is probably creating a list of `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`. You might also want to step through your code and make sure you're actually going into the `foreach (MSPorject.Task...)` loop

Comment: When I don't comment "tasks.Add (task);" The following error appears: Cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Task' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' AST

Comment: Change `List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();` to `List<MSProject.Task> tasks = new List<MSProject.Task>();` and then uncomment the `tasks.Add(..);` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my comments, change how you declare your list and then uncomment the add. Now you just have to figure out what you're actually going to do with the list.

```cs
private void Btn_Actualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog theDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (theDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string fileName = theDialog.FileName.ToString();
            Load(fileName);
        }
    }

    public new string Load(string fileName)
    {
        MSProject.ApplicationClass app = null;
        string retVal = "";
        List<MSProject.Task> tasks = new List<MSProject.Task>();

        try
        {
            // execute the Microsoft Project Application
            app = new MSProject.ApplicationClass();

            // Do not display Microsoft Project
            app.Visible = false;

            // open the project file.
            if (app.FileOpen(fileName, true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, MSProject.PjPoolOpen.pjPoolReadOnly, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing))
            {
                // go through all the open projects--there should only be one
                foreach (MSProject.Project proj in app.Projects)
                {
                    // go through all the tasks in the project
                    foreach (MSProject.Task task in proj.Tasks)
                    {
                        // add Microsoft Project Task to arraylist                          
                        //tasks.Add(new Task(task));
                        tasks.Add(task);
                        //List<Task> tasks1 = new List<Task>();

                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                retVal = "The MS Project file " + fileName + " could not be opened.";
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            retVal = "Could not process the MS Project file " + fileName + "." + System.Environment.NewLine + ex.Message + System.Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace;
        }

        // close the application if is was opened.
        if (app != null)
        {
            app.Quit(MSProject.PjSaveType.pjDoNotSave);
        }
        return retVal;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You were so close.  Unfortunately in your loop, you kept re-creating your list of tasks, instead of creating it once and adding each `Task` to the existing `List`.

```
//First, declare your task list outside of any of your event handlers
List<MSProject.Task> tasks = new List<MSProject.Task>();

private void Btn_Actualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog theDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    // ... and the rest of that code
```

Within your `Load()` function, change your code like thisTry this instead:

```
public new string Load(string fileName)
{
    MSProject.ApplicationClass app = null;
    string retVal = "";
    //if the list object hasn't been created yet, then create it now
    if (tasks == null) 
        tasks = new List<MSProject.Task>();
    else //if it was already created, just clear it.
        tasks.Clear();

    try
    {
        //... (I didn't paste all of the code. It is still required, of course.)

            // go through all the open projects--there should only be one
            foreach (MSProject.Project proj in app.Projects)
            {
                // go through all the tasks in the project
                foreach (MSProject.Task task in proj.Tasks)
                {
                    // add Microsoft Project Task to arraylist                          
                    tasks.Add(task); //<-- this was the correct line, uncommented
                }
        //... (I didn't paste all of the code. It is still required, of course.)
```

@Michael Jones also had good advice.  The name `Task` is re-used by a few libraries. It is best to include the namespace `MSProject`, to avoid any ambiguity and related errors.

Comment: The following error occurs: The type 'System.Collections.Generic.List <Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Task>' cannot be implicitly converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List <System.Threading.Tasks.Task>'

Comment: Right.  You can't just declare `List<Task>`.  You must explicitly use `List<MSProject.Task>`. Search your code for anywhere you declared it as just Task, and replace it with MSProject.Task.